# SQL Server 2000 : I am using a procedure to update a column value in a huge database with million rows but it is still taking huge time

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2000

Below is the logic I am using inside my stored procedure to update my columns in a huge database and I am new to SQL Server and need a bit on best practice to reduce the processing time.

I am trying to create indexes from different knowledge source to achieve it but still couldn't make it right so need expertise advice on how to address this performance issue

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tmp_my_table') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.tmp_my_table;

CREATE INDEX [tmp_ind] ON [dbo].[tmp_fact_table](col1, col2, col3_flag, col4) ON [PRIMARY]

SELECT
    DISTINCT
    COL1,
    COL2,
    COL3_FLAG
INTO
    dbo.tmp_my_table
FROM
 dbo.tmp_fact_table
WHERE
    COL4 = 1

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [tmp_WO_COL2_tony_ind]  ON dbo.tmp_my_table (COL1,   COL2, COL3_FLAG) ON [PRIMARY]
CREATE INDEX [tmp_FACT_QS_DETAIL_WO_COL2_MIC_ind] ON [dbo].[tmp_fact_table](COL1, COL2, colmc3) ON [PRIMARY]

UPDATE
    FCT
SET
    FCT.COL3_FLAG   = TMP.COL3_FLAG 
FROM
dbo.tmp_fact_table          FCT
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.tmp_my_table                            TMP
    ON FCT.COL1 = TMP.COL1
    AND FCT.COL2            = TMP.COL2
WHERE
    FCT.colmc3  = 1
```

Comment: SQL Server **2000** is sooooo waaaaaaay beyond supported (even SQL Server **2005** is no longer officially supported....) - you should ***really*** upgrade to a more recent version!

Comment: yes i know i have proposed that to the team and not in my hands..is there anything i can do to the above code to tune it better

Comment: the tmp_FACT_QS_DETAIL_WO_COL2_MIC_ind index should probably be colmc3, COL1, COL2

Answer (score 1):

First suggestion, you could try adding SQL command:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.tmp_my_table
```

after the CREATE INDEX statements in your code.  This will force SQL Server to build latest statistics for these indexes.

You really need to capture the Query Execution plan details to show how SQL Server is executing the UPDATE statement, and if the indexes are being used effectively.